# How to forward an argument to a template member function to a member base class pointer in C++

Tags: c++, templates

I have a class `Foo` which uses CRTP to inherit a template method from a parent class and avoid having to provide literally dozens of individual member methods. Something like this:

```
class Foo : public SomeBarClass<Foo>
{
//..
//from SomeBarClass
public:
    template <class T> void onMsg(T* msg);

private:
    IFoxMod* foxMod_;
};
```

Now, in the implementation for `onMsg`, I would like something like this:

```
template <class T>
void Foo::onMsg(T* msg)
{
    if (foxMod_->shouldDoStuff(msg))
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

and there can be many `foxMod_` types (one of them instantiated in the `Foo` constructor by name given in config file) as long as they abide by the common interface of providing a `bool shouldDoStuff` method. The problem, is that this leads me to define the following:

```
struct IFoxMod
{
    virtual ~IFoxMod() {}
    template <class T> shouldDoStuff(T* msg) = 0;
};
```

for all of the `FoxMods` to implement (like, `class redMountainLogic : public IFoxMod` might have it's own way of discerning, when it is appropiate to do stuff).

This is illegal though because one cannot have virtual templates and I'm trying to find a workaround for it. Basically, I need to have dynamic dispatch, but the argument I am passing is a template. I can't think of a workaround.

Comment: Generally messages are polymorphic in some fasion. A message base and then sub-types of that.

Comment: Have you already looked at http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[c%2B%2B]+dynamic+dispatch+template? There are quite a few questions, which look promising.

Comment: It does feel that IFoxMod should be templated on T too... But I guess that it is what you were trying to avoid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Virtual function tables don't seem to get along well with template specializations.  Not too surprising.  VFTs are generally based on declaration order, which doesn't really exist with templates.  One solution is to manually recreate VFTs.

Here's an example.  It could probably be a little cleaner, but it works.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

// Message.h

template<int n>
struct MessageByInt {
  typedef int Msg;
};

struct MessageOfHope {
  int a;
  int b;
  static const int id = 0;
};
template<> struct MessageByInt<MessageOfHope::id> { typedef MessageOfHope Msg; };

struct MessageOfDoom {
  int b;
  int c;
  static const int id = 1;
};
template<> struct MessageByInt<MessageOfDoom::id> { typedef MessageOfDoom Msg; };

const int nMessages = 2;

// IFoxMod.h

typedef bool(*callback)(void*);

struct IFoxMod {
  callback vtable[nMessages];
  template<typename MSG>
  bool ShouldDoWork(MSG* msg) {
    return vtable[MSG::id](msg);
  }
};

template<typename TESTER, int n>
struct filler {
  typedef typename MessageByInt<n>::Msg MSG;
  typedef typename TESTER::template Tester<MSG> Tester;
  static void fill(IFoxMod* impl) {
    impl->vtable[n] = reinterpret_cast<callback>(&Tester::ReallyShouldDoWork);
    filler<TESTER,n-1>::fill(impl);
  }
};

template<typename TESTER>
struct filler<TESTER,-1>{
  static void fill(IFoxMod* impl) {
  }
};

// RedFox.h

struct RedFoxTester {
  template<typename MSG>
  struct Tester { // This struct exists to allow partial specialization
    static bool ReallyShouldDoWork(MSG* msg) {
      return msg->b == 2;
    }
  };
};

struct RedFoxMod : public IFoxMod {
  RedFoxMod() {
    filler<RedFoxTester,nMessages-1>::fill(this);
  }
};

//Main

main() {
  IFoxMod* fm = new RedFoxMod();
  MessageOfHope mohb2 = {1, 2};
  MessageOfDoom modb2 = {2, 3};
  MessageOfHope mohbn2 = {2, 3};
  MessageOfDoom modbn2 = {1, 2};
  cout << fm->ShouldDoWork(&mohb2) << ", " << fm->ShouldDoWork(&modb2) << endl;
  cout << fm->ShouldDoWork(&mohbn2) << ", " << fm->ShouldDoWork(&modbn2) << endl;
}
```

Comment: Interesting, it does require modifying the messages types themselves though. need to play around with it a bit to understand it.